# ASCII spaces and character removal

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, io, ascii

I have to write a program which takes three inputs and uses those to determine how to display an ASCII word art font as defined by a text file. I am getting the output almost correct however my program incorrectly deals with spaces totally omitting them from things like HOW DO.
This is my code:

```
hi = input('Height: ')
wi = input('Width: ')
tx = input('Text: ')
hi = int(hi)
output = [[] for _ in range(hi)]
with open("font.txt") as fi:
  lines = fi.readlines()

for character in tx:
  offset = int(cd[character])
  start = offset * hi
  end = start + hi 
  letter = lines[start:end] 
  for outputline, letterline in zip(output, letter):
      outputline.append(letterline.rstrip('\n'))
for line in output:
  print(''.join(line))
```

And my output

```
Height: 8
Width: 9
Text: APPLE STORES ARE BAD FOR YOUR HEALTH
 _______  _______  _______  _        _______  _______ _________ _______  _______  _______  _______  _______  _______  _______  ______   _______  ______   _______  _______  _______           _______           _______           _______  _______  _       _________         
(  ___  )(  ____ )(  ____ )( \      (  ____ \(  ____ \\__   __/(  ___  )(  ____ )(  ____ \(  ____ \(  ___  )(  ____ )(  ____ \(  ___ \ (  ___  )(  __  \ (  ____ \(  ___  )(  ____ )|\     /|(  ___  )|\     /|(  ____ )|\     /|(  ____ \(  ___  )( \      \__   __/|\     /|
| (   ) || (    )|| (    )|| (      | (    \/| (    \/   ) (   | (   ) || (    )|| (    \/| (    \/| (   ) || (    )|| (    \/| (   ) )| (   ) || (  \  )| (    \/| (   ) || (    )|( \   / )| (   ) || )   ( || (    )|| )   ( || (    \/| (   ) || (         ) (   | )   ( |
| (___) || (____)|| (____)|| |      | (__    | (_____    | |   | |   | || (____)|| (__    | (_____ | (___) || (____)|| (__    | (__/ / | (___) || |   ) || (__    | |   | || (____)| \ (_) / | |   | || |   | || (____)|| (___) || (__    | (___) || |         | |   | (___) |
|  ___  ||  _____)|  _____)| |      |  __)   (_____  )   | |   | |   | ||     __)|  __)   (_____  )|  ___  ||     __)|  __)   |  __ (  |  ___  || |   | ||  __)   | |   | ||     __)  \   /  | |   | || |   | ||     __)|  ___  ||  __)   |  ___  || |         | |   |  ___  |
| (   ) || (      | (      | |      | (            ) |   | |   | |   | || (\ (   | (            ) || (   ) || (\ (   | (      | (  \ \ | (   ) || |   ) || (      | |   | || (\ (      ) (   | |   | || |   | || (\ (   | (   ) || (      | (   ) || |         | |   | (   ) |
| )   ( || )      | )      | (____/\| (____/\/\____) |   | |   | (___) || ) \ \__| (____/\/\____) || )   ( || ) \ \__| (____/\| )___) )| )   ( || (__/  )| )      | (___) || ) \ \__   | |   | (___) || (___) || ) \ \__| )   ( || (____/\| )   ( || (____/\   | |   | )   ( |
|/     \||/       |/       (_______/(_______/\_______)   )_(   (_______)|/   \__/(_______/\_______)|/     \||/   \__/(_______/|/ \___/ |/     \|(______/ |/       (_______)|/   \__/   \_/   (_______)(_______)|/   \__/|/     \|(_______/|/     \|(_______/   )_(   |/     \|
```

Note how the space (which should be the same size as the other characters) doesn’t appear.

Comment: Where is `cd` defined? [you seem to have some unnecessary initializers - duplicate `hi` and unnecessary `wi` and 'fi']

Comment: this is cd: `cd = {'A' : 0,
'B': 1,
'C': 2,
'D': 3,
'E': 4,
'F': 5,
'G': 6,
'H': 7,
'I': 8,
'J': 9,
'K': 10,
'L': 11,
'M': 12,
'N': 13,
'O': 14,
'P': 15,
'Q': 16,
'R': 17,
'S': 18,
'T': 19,
'U': 20,
'V': 21,
'W': 22,
'X': 23,
'Y': 24,
'Z': 25,
' ': 28}`

Comment: Are you sure there are lines of spaces at the appropriate position in the font.txt file, `print("XXX{}XXX".format(lines[28*hi]))` ? Any reason the `' '` index in `cd` is 28 and not 26?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking for a solution still:

```
for character in tx:
  offset = int(cd[character])
  start = offset * hi
  end = start + hi
  if character == ' ':
    lines[start:end] = [' ' * int(wi) for _ in range(int(hi))]
  letter = lines[start:end]
```